# Django - static folder not in the base project

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I am having some trouble moving my 'static' folder out of the base 'django_project' project. From my experience, Django has looked for the 'static' folder inside of the base project, but it just seemed ugly to me and I wanted to move it next to all of my other Django applications.

Here is my current file directory setup.

```
/home/django/django_project/
    /django_project/
    /myapplication/
    /templates/
    /static/
```

Right now, the 'templates' folder works fine and I can find all of my template files without any trouble. However, I cannot find any static files, the static setup always tricks me up.

Here is my settings.py file for the 'django_project' base project.

```
...

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Go back one directory from this file and move into the 'static' folder
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '..', 'static')),
)

# Template files (HTML)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/home/django/django_project/templates/',
)
```

Can anyone write out the STATIC_URL or STATICFILES_DIR so that it will point to my '/home/django/django_project/static/' folder? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Or just a 404 when trying to access a static file?

Comment: Just a 404 when I look at the page source and click on the link where it includes the static file. The website still shows, just without the static files.

Comment: My only thought is that `__file__` isn't what you are thinking it is. Have you tried printing the value of STATICFILES_DIRS into debug after setting it? What value does it have?

Comment: When I print out the contents of STATICFILES_DIR into a log file from the 'settings.py' file, it prints '/home/django/django_project/static' which is the location of my static folder.

Comment: Can you give us the full path of your settings.py file?

Comment: This all looks correct to me. What are you using in your urls.py to serve the static files?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this, it is much cleaner.

```
STATIC_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '..', 'static'))

STATIC_URL = '/static/' # You may find this is already defined as such.

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
STATIC_PATH,
)
```

STATICFILE_DIRS - This specifies the location of the static directory on your local disk

STATIC_URL - This specifies the URL to access the static media from the web server.

Say you have dragontoothless.jpg file in your static directory. To serve it from your html page, you would use something like this.

```
<img src="/static/dragontoothless.jpg" />
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by putting the static file inside another folder and create staticfiles dir as : STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/another folder'),]

Answer (score 0):

Note:

`os.path.abspath(filename)` returns an absolute path as seen from your current working directory. It does no checking whether the file actually exists.

`os.path.dirname` will look up the directory Return the directory name of pathname path.To get the dirname of the absolute path, use `os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))`

> BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(**file**))

And the static url is

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

> STATICFILES_DIRS = [
>       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
>   ]

Answer (score -3):

Try this in settings.py

STATIC_ROOT = '/path/to/static/folder'

Just change the right hand side to the absolute path of your static folder.